# How to match values from one list to unique values in dictionary of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So my input values are as follows:

```
temp_dict1 = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,5,5], 'C':[6,6,7,8]}
temp_dict2 = {}
val = [5]
```

The list `val` may contain more values, but for now, it only contains one. My desired outcome is:

```
>>>temp_dict2
{'B':[5]}
```

The final dictionary needs to only have the keys for the lists that contain the item in the list `val`, and only unique instances of that value in the list. I've tried iterating through the two objects as follows:

```
for i in temp_dict1:
    for j in temp_dict1[i]:
        for k in val:
            if k in j:
                temp_dict2.setdefault(i, []).append(k)
```

But that just returns an `argument of type 'int' is not iterable` error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Because `j` is an `int` and `if k in j` is trying to iterate over it. I am guessing that you want to iterate on `i` instead and then can remove the line `for j in temp_dict1[i]`.

Comment: that doesn't sound conceptually sane: what is your desired outcome if `5` appears in `'B'` and `'C'`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller If temp_dict1 was as follows:
`temp_dict1 = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[5,5,5], 'C':[5,5,6,6,7,8]}` I would want temp_dict2 to return: `{'A':[5],'B':[5],'C'[5]}`. I know that may seem odd, for my task, it would get the job done.

Comment: Ok, how does `temp_dict` then look like if `val = [5, 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your dictionary to cover some more cases:

```
temp_dict1 = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,5,6], 'C':[6,6,7,8]}
temp_dict2 = {}
val = [5, 6]

for item in val:
    for key, val in temp_dict1.items():
        if item in val:
            temp_dict2.setdefault(key, []).append(item)

print(temp_dict2)
# {'B': [5, 6], 'C': [6]}
```

Or, the same using list comprehension (looks a bit hard to understand, not recommended).

```
temp_dict2 = {}
[temp_dict2.setdefault(key, []).append(item) for item in val for key, val in temp_dict1.items() if item in val]
```

Comment: Why a list comprehension? Just use a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, because I'm using the `dict.setdefault()` function, and I don't think it can be used inside a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison with [@KeyurPotdar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349032/9209546), this can also be achieved via `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

temp_dict1 = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,5,6], 'C':[6,6,7,8]}
temp_dict2 = defaultdict(list)
val = [5, 6]

for i in val:
    for k, v in temp_dict1.items():
        if i in v:
            temp_dict2[k].append(i)

# defaultdict(list, {'B': [5, 6], 'C': [6]})
```

Comment: In the docs I found that performance of `defaultdict` is better than `setdefault`. But, `defaultdict` comes at a cost of an extra import. So, which one is better in terms of performance?

Comment: Honestly, if you are worried about the milliseconds it takes to import `collections.defaultdict`, don't code in Python. Try C.

Comment: You're right, I just wanted to know which one is better to use (in the future).

Comment: My advice is to follow the documentation. While I haven't looked at the C code optimisation, I trust that the docs say it's optimal for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
temp_dict1 = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'B':[5,5,5], 'C':[6,6,7,8]}
val = [5,6]


def values(dict_,val_):
    default_dict={}
    for i in val_:
        for k,m in dict_.items():
            if i in m:
                if k not in default_dict:
                    default_dict[k]=[i]
                else:
                    default_dict[k].append(i)
    return default_dict
print(values(temp_dict1,val))
```

output:

```
{'B': [5], 'C': [6], 'A': [5, 6]}
```